# Sallen-Key active bandpass first order filter

Tags: active-filter

[image: Sallen-Key active bandpass first order filter]

I have an assignment to manually derive transfer function for this active filter. I tried 2 ways. First I did it with kirchoff and substitution, and I get wrong function, and then I tried control systems approach by dividing it into blocks with feedback, but the function takes almost half a page. Is there an easy way to derive it? I found only provided ffunctions for this and that wont do.

Thanks!

Update: I added link here to my calculations. Va, Vb and Vc denote the nodes. I checked twice, could not find mistakes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuNuC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using classical node-mesh analysis here but rather the fast analytical circuits techniques (FACTs). I am not saying they are the best path here but I could derive the transfer function of this second-order filter quite quickly with the help of a few individual sketches I could fix in case of problems. The generalized transfer function of a 2nd-order filter is defined as

\$H(s)=\frac{H_0+s(H^2\tau_2+H^3\tau_3)+s^2H^{32}\tau_3\tau_{32}}{1+s(\tau_2+\tau_3)+s^2(\tau_3\tau_{32})}\$

The time constants in the denominators are found by setting the excitation to  0 (reduce \$V_{in}\$ to 0 V and replace it by a short circuit) and "looking" at the individual resistance driving each capacitor. The resistance multiplied by the capacitor it drives forms the time constants \$\tau\$ we want to determine the denominator \$D(s)\$. Then, we look for the gain of this circuit in dc, when \$s=0\$ and it gives us \$H_0\$. Finally, we determine the gain of this filter when some of its capacitors are set in their hi-frequency state. For instance, if I replace \$C_3\$ by a short circuit (its hi-frequency state), the gain \$H^3=0\$ and you continue with the rest of the gains to form \$N(s)\$. The sketches appear below:

[image]

When you have determined all these time constants (you obviously need KVL and KCL here), you gather all the elements in Mathcad to obtain the final expression that I put in a *low-entropy* form, making the band-pass gain clearly appearing.

[image]

and it you plot the whole thing, you have:

[image]

The FACTs are an excellent way of deriving transfer functions in a swift and efficient manner. I have gone through individual sketches to determine the \$a_i\$ and \$b_i\$ of \$N(s)\$ and \$D(s)\$ meaning that if I observe a deviation at the end between simulation and the Mathcad plot, I can fix the guilty coefficient immediately, something I could not do with the classical approach. If you want to know more about FACTs, have a look at the seminar taught at APEC 2016

http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

but also at the numerous transfer functions derived in the book

http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/List%20of%20FACTs%20examples.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would choose for manually derive the transfer function:

- Start with the general formula for feedback:

  **H(s)=Hf/(1/Acl+Hb)**

  with Hf=Forward function, Hb=backward function (feedback factor) and Acl=closed loop gain of the opamp.
- Hf=Vp/V1 for Vout=0 and Hb=Vp/Vout for Vin=0. (Vp=Voltage at pos input).
- Acl=(1+R6/R7) (in your case: Acl=+2)

Using this method, you have split the whole task into two parts. Finally, you have to rearrange the function with the aim to get a second-order polynominal in the denominator.